# php array_unique bug in 2d ARRAY

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm working on Array list with have many duplication

I use array_unique

```
foreach ($aData as $test) {
   preg_match( "~http://www.site.com/.*?/~", $test,$match) ;
      $a[] = $match;

}
```

output

```
Array ( 

    [0] => Array ( [0] => */liars-all-2013-hdrip-xvid-s4a/ ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => */liars-all-2013-hdrip-xvid-s4a/ ) 
    [2] => Array ( ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => */liars-all-2013-hdrip-xvid-s4a/ ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => */mt-zion-2013-dvdrip-xvid-fihvid/ ) 
    [5] => Array ( [0] => */mt-zion-2013-dvdrip-xvid-fihvid/ ) 
    [6] => Array ( [0] => */mt-zion-2013-dvdrip-xvid-fihvid/ ) 
    [7] => Array ( [0] => */the-ghastly-love-of-johnny-x-2012-webrip-xvid-fan0n/ ) 
    [8] => Array ( [0] => */the-ghastly-love-of-johnny-x-2012-webrip-xvid-fan0n/ ) 
    [9] => Array ( [0] => */the-ghastly-love-of-johnny-x-2012-webrip-xvid-fan0n/ ) 
    [10] => Array ( [0] => */kung-fu-panda-good-croc-bad-croc-2013-dvdrip-x264-ac3-deep1007/ ) 
    [11] => Array ( [0] => */kung-fu-panda-good-croc-bad-croc-2013-dvdrip-x264-ac3-deep1007/ ) 
    [12] => Array ( [0] => */kung-fu-panda-good-croc-bad-croc-2013-dvdrip-x264-ac3-deep1007/ ) 
    [13] => Array ( [0] => */a-viking-saga-the-darkest-day-2013-1080p-bluray-x264-ulshd/ ) 
    [14] => Array ( [0] => */a-viking-saga-the-darkest-day-2013-1080p-bluray-x264-ulshd/ ) 
    [15] => Array ( [0] => */a-viking-saga-the-darkest-day-2013-1080p-bluray-x264-ulshd/ ) 
    [16] => Array ( [0] => */dead-man-down-2013-extras-720p-bluray-x264-phd/ ) 
    [17] => Array ( [0] => */dead-man-down-2013-extras-720p-bluray-x264-phd/ ) 
    [18] => Array ( [0] => */dead-man-down-2013-extras-720p-bluray-x264-phd/ ) 
    [19] => Array ( [0] => */spider-baby-1968-720p-bluray-x264-geckos/ ) 
    [20] => Array ( [0] => */spider-baby-1968-720p-bluray-x264-geckos/ ) 
    [21] => Array ( [0] => */spider-baby-1968-720p-bluray-x264-geckos/ ) 
    [22] => Array ( [0] => */drift-2013-bluray-720p-750mb-direct-download/ ) 
    [23] => Array ( [0] => */drift-2013-bluray-720p-750mb-direct-download/ ) 
    [24] => Array ( [0] => */drift-2013-bluray-720p-750mb-direct-download/) 
    [25] => Array ( [0] => */beautiful-creatures-2013-720p/ ) 
    [26] => Array ( [0] => */beautiful-creatures-2013-720p/ ) 
    [27] => Array ( [0] => */beautiful-creatures-2013-720p/ ) 
    [28] => Array ( [0] => */death-race-3-inferno-2012-bluray-720p-direct-download/ ) 
    [29] => Array ( [0] => */death-race-3-inferno-2012-bluray-720p-direct-download/ ) 
    [30] => Array ( [0] => */death-race-3-inferno-2012-bluray-720p-direct-download/ ) 
)
```

It's look like array_unique cant go deep in to array like : `[]**[x]**` 
so only thing i get after array_unique is my first [0][string]
I tried to use only $match but its only show me last string which is useless

So how could I resolve this BUG?

Comment: Can you please surround this output around <pre> tag ?

Comment: Start by realizing that misusing a function is not a bug. At least not a bug in the function. Then `$a[] = $match[0];`. You will also want to do that only if the `preg_match` succeeds (that's a bug as well).

Comment: Or even more: start realizing that it's highly unlikely (in next months) you get your code working wrong due to bug in php.

Comment: $resuly1 = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $a))); with this solved this problem :)

Comment: @madman: That is a **horrible** way to do things, it is unbelievably slow compared to the alternatives and it will only work on specific types of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

By default `array_unique` [compares the items as if they are string](http://php.net/array_unique), which means that it actually converts the arrays to string (and any array casted to string will be the same - the string 'Array'). So you have to do:

`$a = array_unique($a, SORT_REGULAR)`